# /dev/tcp not present in LINUX

Tags: linux, unix

I'am porting C/pro*c codes from UNIX to LINUX.  The code is:

```
#define __NFDBIT       (8 * sizeof(unsigned long))
#define __FD_SETSIZ    1024
#define __FDSET_LONG   (__FD_SETSIZ/__NFDBIT)
typedef struct {
    unsigned long fds_bits [__FDSET_LONG];
} __ernel_fd_set;

typedef __ernel_fd_set           fd_set_1;
int main()
{
    fd_set_1 listen_set;
    int listen_sd;
    int socket_id;
    FD_ZERO(&listen_set);
    socket_id = t_open("/dev/tcp", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK, (struct t_info *) 0);
    return 0;
}
if ( socket_id <0 )
{
    exit(FAILURE);
}
```

In UNIX the value of socket_id is > 0 in Linux it is -1.  Reason is in UNIX under directory /dev the file tcp is present.  But in LINUX it is under /dev this tcp file is not present.   Also in UNIX this tcp file is character special file which is different from normal file.

Is there any way to create same character special file in LINUX as in UNIX or how to proceed this further?

Comment: you might check on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ if you dont get much feedback here..

Comment: thanks fduff.. I posted in unix.stackexchange.come now.

Comment: ... [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38780/dev-tcp-not-present-in-linux).

Comment: Please wait or flag for a moderator to migrate your question, please don't cross-post. Thanks. /cc @fduff

Answer (score 1):

Solaris uses the `ndd /dev/tcp [value = something]` to change system tcp configuration on a running kernel.  Linux does not do that.

In Linux you write to /proc/sys/net/ipv4/*  (* == lots of files).  Other values for tcp are changed
in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, as a result Linux has no ndd equivalent and no /dev/tcp.

Creating a /dev/tcp out of thin air is not going to give you access to kernel values via a socket.
What is the function of the socket?  you will have to research how to do that using your code and a system admin guide for RH.

If this was compiled with libwrap or some other TCP wrapper library (on Solaris) you will have to look here:

http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-tcpwrappers-access.html

to figure out how to redo your code for Linux.  It is kind of messy in my opinion - TCP wrappers from Soalris -> Linux, that is.

Comment: Thanks Jim for your information.  But I really have no idea if this was compiled with libwarp.  And on solaris I dont see libwarp but it is there in Linux. I need to analyse code to redo.

Comment: On solaris: ldd [compiled executable file name]  shows you how something is linked - what libraries are linked to make the executable